# How to add reflectivity to the golden ring in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, blender

I have an stl file of the gold ring mesh exported from the blender. When I imported it into three JS and add image texture to get the gold metal effect, the texture is not getting applied properly.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code,

```
loader.load( objaddress, stladdress, function ( object ) {

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {                               
                    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("Gold.jpg")});
                                child.material = material;

                      }

                  } );
```

This is the jpg file url I've used:
http://cdn.designbeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/7.gold-textures.jpg

Comment: did you try to change the material to `MeshPhongMaterial` ,pease check the link http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial

Comment: Yep i did changed the material to Phong still not working. When i used Face material i'm getting error in the Three js source itself

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle or similar or post your code(or similar testcase), as its difficult to pinpoint the issue with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the geometry is loaded from the external file, use THREE js ShaderMaterial to create the material for the loaded geometry. Inside the ShaderMaterial specify the image texture along with the smoothness, noise, wrapping to get a better look and feel.

For reference: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial

Here is the code to create the Shader material for the geometry,

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                    uniforms: {
                       tMatCap: {
                            type: 't',
                            value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('Gold.jpg')
                        },
                        time: {
                            type: 'f',
                            value: 0
                        },
                        bump: {
                            type: 'f',
                            value: 0
                        },
                        noise: {
                            type: 'f',
                            value: .04
                        },
                        useNormal: {
                            type: 'f',
                            value: 0
                        },
                        normalScale: {
                            type: 'f',
                            value: .5
                        },
                        normalRepeat: {
                            type: 'f',
                            value: 1
                        } });
```